# Conversion to string or int type in PHP

Tags: php, type-conversion

I have some problems trying to convert some numeric value to string or integer.

```
$value = 0180; //without format
$conversion = (string) $value;
$conversionInt = (int) $value;
```

That code give me the value '1' and I don't know how can obtain the value '180' (is what I need). I try too the strval() function from php and have the same result.

Comment: Numbers with a leading zero are treated as __octal__ values, and `0180` is an invalid octal value... [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

```
 <?php

$value = "0180"; //without format it is octal notation, with format it is a string
$conversion = (string) $value;
$conversionInt = intval($value);
echo $conversion;
echo "ad";
echo $conversionInt;exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
$value = "0180";
$conversion = $value;
$conversionInt = (int) $value;
```

Comment: A good answer explains ___why___; bad answers simply say "do this"..... what category does your answer come under?

Answer (score 0):

this is an octal number. PHP treats it as octal, so if you type the value yourself, type it in quotes. If you get the value as a return, then it's a string, not a number. So, if it is a string, then you can use *ltrim*:

```
$str = ltrim('0180', '0');
```

Why it gives you exactly "1" as a result when you type it as an octal, is because prior to PHP 7, if an invalid digit was given in an octal integer (i.e. 8 or 9), the rest of the number was ignored. Since PHP 7, a parse error is emitted ([PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)). This invalid digit is "8" in your case, so the only one valid digit is taken: "1".